# Python continue with while

Tags: python, loops

There seems to be some serious problem with continue in Python:
for eg:

```
for i  in range(1,10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
         continue
     print i
```

works as intended, but

```
i = 0

while(i < 10):
    if i %2 == 0:   
        continue
    i += 1
    print i
```

the while loop never terminates!

Comment: `i % 2 == 0` is True *immediately*.

Comment: Rule of thumb: whenever you suspect that Python has *some serious problem* triple-check your assumptions. Python has had a `continue` statement for almost 20 years now, I'm sure any serious problems would have been discovered a long time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loop does not do the same thing as your `for` loop; the `for` loop starts at *1* and always increments `i`.

Move the `i += 1` *before* the even test:

```
i = 0

while(i < 10):
    i += 1
    if i % 2 == 0:   
        continue
    print i
```

because `0 % 2 == 0` is `True`, so you *always* continue, skipping the `i += 1` and `print i` statements.

Comment: I think continue meant skipping if a certain condition is met. so it keeps skipping `i` but doesn't increment it?. I thought if it skipped `i` then it'll move on to the next `i`in the for loop. why does it go to an infinite loop?

Comment: Because if you skip `i += 1` too it means `i` is never changed. That in turn means the condition remain forever true

Answer (score 5):

Your `i` is never incremented in the second **snippet**. Remove the continue.

```
i = 0
while(i < 10):
    if i %2 == 0:   # i == 0; continue without increment the value of i <-- stuck here!
        continue
    i += 1
    print i
```

Comment: or increment before the continue.

Comment: why?the continue stuff should happen only if i is even,for the rest it should work.Can you give the code with while loop which works like the for loop I wrote in question.

Comment: i will always remain zero (which is even) in your while loop.