# What is wrong with this converted loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm learning how to program in Python and I ran into this problem. There's supposed to be something wrong with the converted while loop but I can't figure out what it is. I'm a bit stumped on this.

For loop (right):

```
for i in range(4):
  if i % 3 == 0:
    continue

  sum += i
```

While loop (wrong):

```
i = 0

while i < 4:
  if i % 3 == 0:
    continue

  sum += i
  i += 1
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point out the error in this code. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python continue with while](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422695/python-continue-with-while)

Answer (score 2):

In your while loop, you must also increment `i` before you `continue`.